# Grub does not start automatically

Tags: boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 20.10 installed in dual boot with Windows 10. The problem is that when I start the PC, Windows starts automatically, without going through Grub first, and to start Ubuntu I am forced to press F9 during boot and start it from the BIOS menu:

[BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y87lu.jpg)

Once "Ubuntu" is selected, Grub is correctly loaded, from which I can choose whether to start it or Windows.

[GRUB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGz5Q.jpg)

My question is, how can I make the Ubuntu partition (where Grub resides) to boot automatically so that I don't have to choose it every time by pressing F9 at boot? From the BIOS options if I go to "Boot order" there is no possibility, I can only select whether to boot from Hard Disk, CD-ROM, USB or network.

PS: If it can be useful, although my BIOS supports UEFI mode, I had to install both systems in Legacy mode, because if I try to set the BIOS to UEFI, when I reboot the computer screen remains completely black without even giving me the option to access the BIOS again (to do so I'm forced to remove the CMOS BIOS battery to reset the BIOS to Legacy mode).